# Difference between normal instantiation and instantiation including method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

Why is in the first case SomeClass only instantiated once, but in the second case n-times, where n is the number of elements in the stream?

```
List<SomeClass> list = stream.map(new SomeClass()::method)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
List<SomeClass> list = stream.map(a -> {return new SomeClass().method(a);})
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The method "method" in this case return the object itself (= return this).

So in the first case the list contains only one object, but n-times. In the second case the list contains n-different objects.

For reproducing the issue:
main:

```
Arrays.asList(true, false, true, false).stream().map(new SomeClass()::method)
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("----------------------");
        
Arrays.asList(true, false, true, false).stream().map(a -> {return new SomeClass().method(a);})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and SomeClass.java:

```
public class SomeClass {
    
    public SomeClass() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    
    public SomeClass method(Boolean b) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new SomeClass()` static part so no new object  is created I think

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Clearly, you are missing some information. Post a verifiable example.

Comment: I added an example for reproducing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method references only comes in four kinds (See "Kinds of method references" in [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)):

- References to a static method
- References to an instance method of a particular object
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type
- Reference to a constructor

There isn't a kind of method reference that "creates a new object every time", whatever that means. `new SomeClass()::methodName` is of the second kind. It refers to the method `methodName` of *one* particular object. That object is a newly created `SomeClass` object. It doesn't create any more `SomeClass` objects when the method is called, because it is a reference to `someMethod` of *that particular* `SomeClass` object that you newly created.

The lambda expression, on the other hand, creates a new `SomeClass` every time it is called, because `new SomeClass()` is inside the `{ ... }`.

Comment: can you tell me what scope of the second kind is? I mean if I have another class with same logic, the instance in method reference is created only 1 or 2?

Comment: @thang this has nothing to do with scope, because method references are not declarations.  And I didn’t quite understand your second question either... can you show some code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, if I create another class with the same code : `List<SomeClass> list = stream.map(new SomeClass()::method).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Now we have 2 class with the same method reference. Will SomeClass() be created with new instance?

Comment: @thang Yes, because there are two `new SomeClass()` calls now.

Answer (score 4):

Because in the first snippet you invoke `new SomeClass()` only once, because this:

```
List<SomeClass> list = stream.map(new SomeClass()::method)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is effectively equal to this:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
List<SomeClass> list = stream.map(a -> s.method(a))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You invoke the method `method()` on the instance `s`, in the first snippet this instance is just not saved into a variable, but used directly

Comment: That's a wrong assumption. It will be wrapped inside a method body.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai I don't quite understand what you mean. Where am I wrong? What is wrapped inside the method body?

Comment: "Is effectively equal to this" is absolutely wrong. `new SomeClass()::method` will be wrapped inside a method body. Turn on `javap` to see it.

Comment: The question is misleading. Given this situation, the issue is hard to reproduce. `a -> {return new SomeClass().method(a);}` and `new SomeClass()::method` have same semantics.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai I cannot reproduce the things you're describing, the bytecode I've looked at is equal for both of the snippets I've shown (excluding of course the loading of the local variable)

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai, they don't have the same sementics. In the first case, `SomeClass` is instanciated upon invocation of the lambda. In the second case, it is instantiated before creating the method reference. If you want to convert the method reference to a lambda, you have to first capture the instance in a local variable (like in Lino's answer), and then declare the lambda as `a -> s.method(a)`.

Comment: It’s a bit misleading to use again a method reference in the equivalent code, as that would need to get translated to an equivalent code (with a captured value) again. Better use `a -> s.method(a)` in the second code. If the expression wasn’t a `new` operation which is never `null`, the equivalent code was like `SomeClass s = Objects.requireNonNull(expression); … a -> s.method(a) …`.

Comment: @Holger I agree, I've replaced the method reference with a lambda